# Android Picasso handling on orientation changed

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I've an adapter which loads images to an ImageView with the Picasso until here everything is ok.
The problem is I'm handling by myself the orientation changes:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

and i cant make to Picasso reload the image and fit it correctly in the imageView after the orientation changed.

```
if (imageUrlString == null) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.image_adega).fit().centerCrop()
                .into(headerHolder.img_store);

    } else {

        Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrlString).fit().into(headerHolder.img_store);
    }
```

And in my activity:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.reloadPicasso(getActivity());
        }
    }
```

XML:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_store"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post what your layout XML file looks like?

Comment: Added the xml snippet

Comment: You shouldn't need to force reload the image after orientation change. The image sizing is controlled by the ImageView. Try adding android:scaleType="centerCrop" to your layout XML

Comment: Can you show what is happening to your imageview post orientation

Comment: Thank you @bodagetta it worked, I've ignored the xml options because i was thinking that Picasso was overriding the xml options.

Comment: Great! I'll write up a formal answer so people who come here in the future will know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alter your layout file to specify the scaling type.

Add

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

to your layout XML file and then when the device is rotated the ImageView will automatically scale the image. You don't need to manually reload the ImageView using Picasso.